# Selenium pass dom element to JQuery and get results back into C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, selenium

So I had a bit of trouble finding how to use JQuery to lookup stuff and pass it back to Selenium C#, but I got it working, so I thought I'd share what I've found.

In particular:

- How to pass IWebElements from C# to JQuery?
- How to get an array of objects back into C# from the results of the javascipt?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering my own question here :)

You can pass webElements to the javascript and access them through `arguments`.

To get the results back into C#, you have to cast to `<IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>>`. For single elements, just use `IWebElement`. One trick for multiple results is you have to call `toArray` on the JQuery result, so that it returns a true array instead of an object.

```
var singleResult = Driver.ExecuteJavaScript<IWebElement>(
            "return $('.my-class')[0]");

IWebElement elementToPass = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("cool-id"));
var results = Driver.ExecuteJavaScript<IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>>(
            "return $(arguments[0]).children('.my-class').toArray()", elementToPass);
```